# Can someone explain this awk quirk?

Tags: awk, cygwin

I have a file that has a bunch of numbers ranging from .000000001 to 1000.

I'm trying to turn it into xml that looks something like this (where the number is multiplied by 10^7 in the name portion:

```
<TickTable Name="Fut_2500">
    <Tick Size="0.0025"/>
</TickTable>
```

I'm using the following awk command (in cygwin):

```
 awk '{print "<TickTable Name=\"Fut_" $0 * 1000000 "\">\n\t<Tick Size=\""$0 * 1 "\"/>\n</TickTable>"}' tick.txt
```

The formatting lookgs good, however, that results in the TickSize number being formatted with the 'e' notation such as 5e-07...:

```
<TickTable Name="Fut_0.5">
    <Tick Size="5e-07"/>
</TickTable>
```

So I tried running the same command, but without multiplying the second instance of the number by * 1:

```
awk '{print "<TickTable Name=\"Fut_" $0 * 1000000 "\">\n\t<Tick Size=\""$0 "\"/>\n</TickTable>"}' tick.txt
```

But now, the formatting becomes all messed up, where if I > to a file, it looks like:

```
<TickTable Name="Fut_0.5">
    <Tick Size=".0000005
"/>
```

and looks like this in cygwin:

```
<TickTable Name="Fut_5">
"/>     <Tick Size=".000005
</TickTable>
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix this? (Easiest way is probably to stop the auto-formatting of the decimals in 'e' notation?

Comment: Learn about [mcve] s. Can't you boil this down to something more like `echo .000000001 | awk '{print $0*1000000 }'` ? There doesn't seem to be any reason that the XML formatting needs to be in your Q. Good luck.

Comment: Ah, cygwin and embedded newlines. Try `dos2unx tick.txt` and rerun. Also read up about `printf` and the `%[n.m]f` option (just search for `%f`). You should be able to find that on [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) .  Good luck.

Comment: That worked! Converting file to unix format fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped.  you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Also note the sections labeled  "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.